# Madelung energy

Tags: solid-state-physics

[image]

I was reading Solid State Physics by Charles Kittel, and equation (19) (in the image above) aroused my confusion. For non-nearest neighbours (indicated in equation(19) as "otherwise") why is the Coulomb potential term the only term that remains when we write the repulsive interaction? Why is the central field repulsive potential term not written?

The image size has become too small perhaps, for which I apologise. Any explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply a choice of approximation that is made here. Since the exponential function decays much faster than the $R^{-1}$ term, it can be argued that for large enough distances (assumed to be anything larger than nearest neighbors), the exponential term is negligible.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you. Probably I was trying to think about it in too complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small elaboration on the already appeared correct explanation in term of range of the exponential  vs the coulomb term.

Energy in ionic systems is dominated by the electrostatic contribution (Madelung's term). However, a purely coulombic interaction would not allow a stable system (attraction between unlike charges is unlimited from below). The stabilizing effect comes from the short-range repulsion due to the overlap between the ionic wavefunctions. Such a term decays exponentially with distance.

In a solid ionic-system with compact structure, like NaCl or CsCl,  unlike charges get as closest as possible, limited only by the repulsive interaction due to the overlap of electronic wavefunctions. Like charges experience two repulsive forces. One is due to the coulomb interaction, the other to the short rage repulsion. However, at the distance of first neighbors, Coulomb repulsion dominates and pushes like atoms towards larger distances, making them second neighbors. moreover at those distances, repulsive interaction due to the electronic overlap is negligeable.

Interestingly, such an effect is visible not only in the solid but also in the liquid structure as determined by scattering experiments.